# Using Python/Postfix/SendMail/Mutt to send HTML emails stored as text files

Tags: python, email

I have a directory full of email files, which look like this:

```
From: Scoop <my@email.com>
To: your@email.com
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-type: text/html
Subject: Hello There
X-Header1: some-custom-header
X-Header2: another-custom-header
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=iso-8859-1">
<title>Hello There</title>
</head>
<body>
Some <b>html</b>.
</body>
</html>
```

I'm using Python and was looking for a way to loop over these files/messages and send them to a SMTP server using Python's smtplib. My problem is, you're forced to specify to/from addresses (which I already have in the header of the plain text):

```
message.sendmail('from@email.com', [to@email.com], myfilecontents.as_string())
```

The other alternatives I've thought of (but don't really want to resort to) are dumping those text files into a folder for Postfix/SendMail/Mutt (as a transport), in the hopes that they'll be able to process the plain text files and send them via SMTP to my actual SMTP server.

Any thoughts or experiences on this front would be greatly appreciated.  I'm on an Arch Linux system, if that matters.

Comment: What are you really trying to achieve here? Where have these messages come from?

Comment: I take it that in fact there is a blank line after your message header and before your message body (i.e. before the line `<html>`) ? Otherwise your messages are not valid RFC5322...

Comment: @hochgurgler The messages are generated by a python script (that I have no control over). I'm trying to send a bunch of text files, that happen to be emails, to an smtp server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you fix the format of the file by placing a newline after the headers, you can use `email.parser` to parse the file for the headers required for the envelope.

Answer (score 0):

Python's smtplib is actually being correct.

E-mail messages *alone* can't be dispatched correctly. You need the message **and** an envelope sender and an envelope recipient.

Consider the case of "Bcc". The recipients aren't specified within the message, but the message is supposed to be delivered to those people.

"Bcc" works in "proper" e-mail processing systems because messages in flight always have envelope senders and recipients associated with them.

Sometimes a person comes up and "just wants to send a message", and "doesn't care about Bcc", and makes a fudged system which hackily does "something", but it's a huge approximation.

It's just about OK for a one-time deal to dispatch a few messages which have gotten lost or something.

But it is not a good approach to be taking for a regular recurring process.

What are you really trying to do here? Where have these messages come from?